# I am having a hard time using Vim online editors along with Vimium

Tags: vim, vimium

I want to know how to use Vimium on the website with vim code editor

Answer (score 0):

Open `vimtutor`. After that, practice. After that, learn other commands, making sure to go slowly and learn by practice and not by memorization.